# Can't get performant Julia Turing model

Tags: julia

I've tried to reproduce the model from a [PYMC3 and Stan comparison](https://gist.github.com/QuantScientist/78f84fbe3c13caa6986505400b6ae987). But it seems to run slowly and when I look at `@code_warntype` there are some things -- `K` and `N` I think -- which the compiler seemingly calls `Any`.

I've tried adding types -- though I can't add types to `turing_model`'s arguments and things are complicated within `turing_model` because it's using autodiff variables and not the usuals. I put all the code into the function `do_it` to avoid globals, because they say that globals can slow things down. (It actually seems slower, though.)

Any suggestions as to what's causing the problem? The `turing_model` code is what's iterating, so that should make the most difference.

```
using Turing, StatsPlots, Random

sigmoid(x) = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x))

function scale(w0::Float64, w1::Array{Float64,1})
    scale = √(w0^2 + sum(w1 .^ 2))
    return w0 / scale, w1 ./ scale
end

function do_it(iterations::Int64)::Chains
    K = 10                         # predictor dimension
    N = 1000                       # number of data samples

    X = rand(N, K)                 # predictors    (1000, 10)

    w1 = rand(K)                   # weights       (10,)
    w0 = -median(X * w1)           # 50% of elements for each class (number)
    w0, w1 = scale(w0, w1)         # unit length (euclidean)
    w_true = [w0, w1...]

    y = (w0 .+ (X * w1)) .> 0.0    # labels
    y = [Float64(x) for x in y]

    σ = 5.0
    σm = [x == y ? σ : 0.0 for x in 1:K, y in 1:K]

    @model turing_model(X, y, σ, σm) = begin

        w0_pred ~ Normal(0.0, σ)
        w1_pred ~ MvNormal(σm)

        p = sigmoid.(w0_pred .+ (X * w1_pred))

        @inbounds for n in 1:length(y)
            y[n] ~ Bernoulli(p[n])
        end
    end

    @time chain = sample(turing_model(X, y, σ, σm), NUTS(iterations, 200, 0.65));

    # ϵ = 0.5
    # τ = 10

    # @time chain = sample(turing_model(X, y, σ), HMC(iterations, ϵ, τ));

    return (w_true=w_true, chains=chain::Chains)
end

chain = do_it(1000)
```

Comment: This doesn't run as written. Can you add enough code to let the example be run? It makes it much easier to diagnose performance problems. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten the two supporting functions which are used in setting up the data. Should run now.

Comment: The type-instability does not  appear about `N` or `K`. `N` and `K` is set to an `Int64` and you never change its binding. Although you set `y` to a `BitArray` and then a `Float64` array, Julia gets rid of the instability issue during compilation. The type-stability is due to the model. I am not sure how `Turing.jl` works but probably this type-instability is expected. I would try asking this question on [Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/) and give a link to here.